# Ruby: check if method is defined before aliasing

Tags: ruby

```
class Test

  def my_print
    p "Print something"
  end
end

class Test

  alias_method :old_print, :my_print
  def my_print
    old_print
    p "Print some more"
  end
end
```

My original Test class is at the top. I then decided to add some more to it, but I decided to alias.

But that assumes my_print is already defined. Is there a short and simple way to check whether a method I'm aliasing is already defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about

```
if Test.method_defined? :my_print
    alias_method :old_print, :my_print
end
```

Comment: hmm that seems like a lot to write but I guess I will have to make do with it lol

Comment: what about writing in one line?

alias_method(:old_print, :my_print) if Test.method_defined? :my_print

Answer (score 3):

since "my_print" is not a class method , but an instance method, you should:

```
if Mod.instance_methods.include? "my_print"
  alias_method :old_print, :my_print
end
```

Comment: You mean `:my_print` (method names are symbols).

Comment: seems that different versions of Ruby have different results. (some returns String Array, some returns Symbol Array. According to its Ruby187 api, the result is String. of course I prefer the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

`if method(:my_print)
  alias_method :old_print, :my_print
end`

Answer (score 0):

### Use `defined?` Method.

You can use the `defined?` method to see if a method has already been defined within the current context/scope:

```
alias_method( :old_print, :my_print ) if defined?( my_print )
```